# Invalid objects while upgrading Oracle 12c to 18c

Tags: database, oracle, upgrade, oracle18c, invalid-object-name

180 objects are invalid in pre-requisite even after running `utlrp.sql` while upgrading oracle 12c to 18c.

When running `EXECUTE DBMS_PREUP.INVALID_OBJECTS`, I am getting APEX packages in the output which I have upgraded from 4.2 to latest 19. See more details here :
[image: here]

Comment: Error: ORA-38824: A CREATE OR REPLACE command may not change the EDITIONABLE property of an existing object. Getting this error on compiling the same package

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to get around this, as APEX 4.2 is not certified with Oracle version greater that 12.1.0.2

[image]

Comment: Hi, i tried above mentioned steps with my APEX_040200 user but still there are 180 invalid objects of the same user that i am not able to compile.

Comment: Error: ORA-38824: A CREATE OR REPLACE command may not change the EDITIONABLE property of an existing object.
Getting this error on compiling the same package

Comment: Updated my answer to show compatibility of APEX 4.2 with Oracle versions